# Python script killed from another script but no signal callback is called

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to kill a script from another script by calling os.kill(PID, signal.SIGTERM). This part works, the process with PID is killed. The thing is I set a signal callback in the killed script but I was not called.

This is how I set the callback

```
signals = signal.valid_signals()
for sig in signals:
    signal.signal(sig, signal_handler)
```

This is my simple callback

```
def signal_handler(signal, *args):
    print("Received signal %d" % signal)
```

And this is how I am killing the prrocess

```
print("Process with %d exist" % pid)
os.kill(pid, signal.SIGINT)
```

Scripts are run under windows. Could you please give me and advice what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it's a Windows issue. Check the Windows note on the [os.kill docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.kill).

> Windows: The signal.CTRL_C_EVENT and signal.CTRL_BREAK_EVENT signals are special signals which can only be sent to console processes which share a common console window, e.g., some subprocesses. Any other value for sig will cause the process **to be unconditionally killed** by the TerminateProcess API, and the exit code will be set to sig. The Windows version of kill() additionally takes process handles to be killed.